# Why should the controlled group in a conditional inclusion be lexically valid when the conditional is false?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

The following program compiles:

```
// #define WILL_COMPILE 
#ifdef WILL_COMPILE
int i = 
#endif

int main()
{   
    return 0;
}
```

GCC Live demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d1ac8698f9421db).

But the following will issue a warning:

```
//#define WILL_NOT_COMPILE
#ifdef WILL_NOT_COMPILE
char* s = "failure
#endif

int main()
{   
    return 0;
}
```

GCC Live demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/469c5c6197a0a81f).

I understand that in the first example, the controlled group is removed by the time the [compilation phase of the translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) is reached. So it compiles without errors or warnings.

But why is lexical validity required in the second example when the controlled group is not going to be included?

Searching online I found this [quote](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html):

> Even if a conditional fails, the controlled text inside it is still run through initial transformations and tokenization. Therefore, it must all be lexically valid C. Normally the only way this matters is that all comments and string literals inside a failing conditional group must still be properly ended.

But this does not state **why** the lexical validity is checked when the conditional fails.

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Both will compile as given, neither will compile when the `#define` is uncommented. But perhaps your compiler is looking for the missing closing `"`. I suggest the answer as to *why* it has to lexically valid is becasue the string might be `char* s = "#endif";`

Comment: I missed to mention that I was using GCC. Updated the question with live demos.

Comment: Because GCC was written that way. Because GCC developers decided so. The C99 standard says that all the directives in this block are ignored. One may say that GCC is not acting standard compliant here. But it's just a warning, which is an implementation dependent.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the C standard. GCC developers would have had some reason to ignore the standard in this matter. Why would they just "decide so"?

Comment: @KamilCuk it is undefined behavior, so gcc is within its rights to diagnose it but could also ignore it.

Comment: @KamilCuk: There are no directives in the conditionally-included block. A directive is something starting with a `#`. And what the standard actually says is the following; note the use of the word "token": "Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the directives’ preprocessing **tokens** are ignored, as are the other preprocessing **tokens** in the group."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why is [something about C] the way it is?" questions can't usually be answered, because none of the people who wrote the 1989 C standard are here to answer questions [as far as I know, anyway] and if they *were* here, it was nearly thirty years ago and they probably don't remember.

However, I can think of a plausible reason why the contents of skipped conditional groups are required to consist of a valid sequence of preprocessing tokens.  Observe that comments are *not* required to consist of a valid sequence of preprocessing tokens:

```
/* this comment's perfectly fine even though it has an unclosed
   character literal inside */
```

Observe also that it is really simple to scan for the end of a comment.  `/*` you look for the next `*/`, `//` you look for the end of the line.  The only complication is that trigraphs and backslash-newline are supposed to be converted first.  Tokenizing the contents of comments would be extra code to no useful purpose.

By contrast, it is not simple to scan for the end of a skipped conditional group, because conditional groups nest.  You have to be looking for `#if`, `#ifdef`, and `#ifndef` as well as `#else` and `#endif`, and counting your depth.  And all of those directives are lexically defined in terms of preprocessor tokens, because that's the most natural way to look for them when you're *not* in a skipped conditional group.  Requiring skipped conditional groups to be tokenizable allows the preprocessor to use the same code to process directives within skipped conditional groups as it does elsewhere.

By default, GCC issues only a warning when it encounters an un-tokenizable line inside a skipped conditional group, an error elsewhere:

```
#if 0
"foo
#endif
"bar
```

gives me

```
test.c:2:1: warning: missing terminating " character
"foo
^
test.c:4:1: error: missing terminating " character
"bar
^~~~
```

This is an intentional leniency, possibly one I introduced myself (it's only been *twenty* years since I wrote a third of GCC's current preprocessor, but I have still forgotten a lot of the details).  You see, the *original* C preprocessor, the one K and R wrote, *did* allow arbitrary nonsense inside skipped conditional groups, because it wasn't built around the concept of tokens in the first place; it transformed text into other text.  So people would put *comments* between `#if 0` and `#endif` instead of `/*` and `*/`, and naturally enough those comments would sometimes contain apostrophes.  So, when Per Bothner and Neil Booth and Chiaki Ishikawa and I replaced GCC's original "C-Compatible Compiler Preprocessor"<sup>1</sup> with the integrated, fully standards-compliant "cpplib", circa GCC 3.0, we felt we needed to cut a little compatibility slack here.

---

<sup>1</sup> Raise your hand if you're old enough to know why RMS thought this name was funny.

Comment: Thanks for giving the plausible reason why it is this way. And for the history lesson too. I don't know why RMS thought the name was funny.

Comment: @PW the abbreviation corresponded to a geopolitical giant of the time, now still important but with a different name, politic. and cultural significance.

Answer (score 2):

In the [translation phase 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) the preprocessor will generate preprocessor tokens and having a `"` end up in the catch all *non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above*
 is undefined behavior. 
See [C11 6.4 Lexical elements p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p3):

> A token is the minimal lexical element of the language in translation phases 7 and 8. The
>   categories of tokens are: keywords, identifiers, constants, string literals, and punctuators.
>   **A preprocessing token is the minimal lexical element of the language in translation
>   phases 3 through 6**. The categories of preprocessing tokens are: header names,
>   identifiers, preprocessing numbers, character constants, string literals, punctuators, and
>   single non-white-space characters that do not lexically match the other preprocessing
>   token categories.69) **If a ' or a " character matches the last category, the behavior is
>   undefined.** ....

For reference the [preprocessing-token](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p1) are:

> preprocessing-token:
>                    header-name
>                    identifier
>                    pp-number
>                    character-constant
>                    string-literal
>                    punctuator
>                    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

Of which the unmatched `"` in your second example matches `non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above`.

Since this is undefined behavior and not a constraint the compiler is not obliged to diagnose it but it is certainly allowed to and using `-pedantic-errors` it even becomes an error [godbolt session](https://godbolt.org/z/q9f_a-). As rici points out it only becomes a constraint violation if the token survives preprocessing.

The [gcc document you cite](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html) basically says the same thing:

> ... Even if a conditional fails, the controlled text inside it is **still run through initial** transformations and **tokenization**. Therefore, it must all be lexically valid C. Normally the only way this matters is that all comments and **string literals inside a failing conditional group must still be properly ended**. ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Upped.

Comment: A more accurate statement would be "Since this is undefined behaviour *and not a constraint*, the compiler is not obliged...". It only becomes a constraint if the illegal token survives preprocessing and needs to be converted to a token. Presumably this relaxation is in place because some compilers, for historical reasons explain by @zwol, did/do silently ignore such errors.

Comment: @rici fair point, adjusted wording. They only way I could see this happening is if preprocessing literally just generated a text file which is not allowed, it needs to generate tokens.

Comment: It just means that the compiler can choose to allow a single quote or apostrophe to be a preprocessing token in certain contexts. If there were a constraint that preprocessing tokens could not be the single characters quote or apostrophe, then a diagnostic would be required and implementations which treated `#if 0` as a kind of multiline comment wouldn't be able to just ignore apostrophes in the unprocessed lines. That was at one time a common implementation, so I'm guessing the standard was written the way it is to avoid castigating those implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The description of *Translation phase 3* (C11 5.1.1.2/3), which happens before preprocessing directives are actioned:

> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of
>   white-space characters (including comments).

And the grammar for *preprocessing-token* is:

> *header-name*
>   *identifier*
>   *pp-number*
>   *character-constant*
>   *string-literal*
>   *punctuator*
>   each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

Note in particular that a *string-literal* is a single preprocessing-token.  The subsequent description (C11 6.4/3) clarifies that:

> If a `'` or a `"` character matches the last category, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So your second code causes undefined behaviour at translation phase 3.

Comment: Thanks for the citations. Upped.